# Where can I find wolves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Wolves? What wolves? I have only spotted *ONE* wolf in playing minecraft for the past two weeks!

Can anyone tell me where I can find one? Is there some sort of biome they prefer? Are the spawning rules for wolves any different from regular critters?

Comment: I found one in a forest biome in about thirty minutes and you just need to keep looking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wolves spawn in taiga and forest biomes only. (However, according to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf), a glitch allows wolves to spawn rarely in all biomes.) They follow the same spawning rules as other passive mobs; they spawn on grass with light level 7 or higher.

My best advice is to find a taiga or forest and run around looking for them.

Comment: blast! Beat me by 21 seconds!

Comment: Muahahahaha! :)

Comment: Protip: Wait until night, and place a few torches in an otherwise dark area (in a forest/taiga). Kill anything that spawns and isn't a wolf. You can easily get wolves in 10 minutes.

Comment: That is all Forest biomes **excepting the Flower Forest biome** ([source](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Wolf#Spawning)).

Answer (score 8):

According to the minecraft wiki,

Wolves spawn in Light level 7 or higher (like all passive mobs), on Grass (again, like all passive mobs), typically in Taiga and Forest biomes, and more commonly during dawn and dusk periods of the day.

They can spawn in groups of 1-8.

Comment: haha, way to beat @Kevin Y!

Comment: ("blast! [Kevin Y] beat me by 21 seconds!" ;P)

Comment: oh, oops! I commented on the wrong answer!

Comment: @Chands - you should give Kevin Y the accepted answer. He had the first answer; it's only fair.

Comment: you're right. i fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can find wolves in areas with snow and lots of trees. Once you find a wolf, you can tame them with bones. Tamed wolves will attack whatever you attack, so be careful not to accidently punch your other pets. You can make tamed wolves sit or stand. ( Warning: If a wolf is sitting down for too long, the wolf will never be able to stand up forever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it : it is a (little) cheat. It will not spawn dogs where there is not, it will locate existing wolves using level datas:

1. Download [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) program and run it.
2. Unfold `saves`, then the folder corresponding to your mod. Select `region` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
3. Check the button `Value` and then put `id` in `name` and `Wolf` in `Value`. Click on `Find` then wait.
4. When it has finished searching, NBTExplorer selected the `id: Wolf` leaf. Just scrolldown: after the leaf `Owner:`, and some other branches, there is one called `Pos`. Expand it, and then you have the dog's pos!

Answer (score -3):

You can find them in the water in the forest